# how to stop setInterval? clearInterval doesn't work

Tags: javascript, boolean, clearinterval

I want to make moving and stop program.
This program has just one button. The button is all of program.
Yeah, It is super simple program.
The program's problem is that the ball doesn't stop.

```
function onSubmit() {
  var tev = setInterval(move, 500);
  if (animate == false) {
    setInterval(move, 500);
    animate = true;
  } else {
    clearInterval(tev);
    animate = false;
  }
}
<input type="button" onclick="onSubmit();" value="Shoot"/>
```

The thing that i want is When i click Shoot button, the ball should move,
click again, stop.
Excuting my code, click once, the ball moves correctly. click again, It doesn't stop. It's my problem.
How to stop the ball?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're resetting `tev` every time you hit the button. Save that value outside of the function and it'll work just fine.

```js
// Save outside of the function so it will keep it's value
var timeoutID;
document.getElementById('clickMe').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // Notice that I'm not re-assigning timeoutID
  // every time I click the button
  if (timeoutID) {
    console.log('Stopped');
    clearInterval(timeoutID);
    
    // Clear out the ID value so we're ready to start again
    timeoutID = null;
  } else {
    timeoutID = setInterval(function() {
      console.log('Rolling...');
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="clickMe">Start/Stop</button>
```

Comment: Can i ask you one thing? When I copy this code and execute, Chrome said "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null".

Comment: @nuroo It's probably because you don't have the button I added for the demo.

Answer (score 0):

```
var moving = false;
var interval;

// handle the click
function handleClick() {
    // if moving set moving to false, otherwise set it to true
    moving = moving ? stop() : start();
}

// start the interval that calls move function and set moving to true
function start() {
    moving = true;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        move();
    }, 500);
}

// clear the interval and set moving to false
function stop() {
    moving = false;
    clearInterval(interval);
}
```